# Apple Devices, NTP-Requests?

Tags: dhcp, iphone, ipad, ntp

Our DHCP delivers the address of an internal (working) NTP-Server. However our firewall reports a "massive" Storm of NTP-Requests (from iPhones, iPads) trying to contact some server on the internet. (it's blocked)

With 8 Devices on the network, it's like 1000 attempts per minute - why doesn't the iDevices take the internal NTP delivered through the DHCP-Scope configuration?

Is this something we could change by configuration, or do the apple-things have hardcoded NTP-Servers?

[image]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try http://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, for beeing unaware, that there is a dedicated "stackexchange" for apple. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this Q/A](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=11772), they do indeed use hardcoded servers. You will probably find that many devices won’t accept anything but the IP configuration from a DHCP server.

However, you can hijack the hardcoded hostname(s):

- time.asia.apple.com
- time.apple.com
- time.euro.apple.com

Simply use your internal DNS to route these to your NTP server’s IP address and you should be good.

Comment: Thx for your hint. Already thought about this, but also considered the case that our NTP-Configuration can be improved to handle iDevices as well.

Comment: Works like a charm :) - silence -